# Android how to record music from media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm working on a project where I'm playing music over url using android build in media player. The things that I want to achieve this is to be able to save the streaming data in a file on sd card. I've tried to do this using android build in media recorder, but it's recording everything around the phone, not only  the sound which is coming from media player.

So my question is which is the best way to achieve this?

Here is an example which I've tested already, but I can't play the mp3 file after that to see if everything went ok :

```
Log.e("URL AGAIN","url : "+url);
            try {
                if(!isrecording){

                    URL urlStream = new URL(url);
                    InputStream inputStream = urlStream.openStream();
                    Log.d("", "urlStream.openStream()");

                    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                    filename += "/deliciousradio.mp3";

                    File outputSource= new File(filename);
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
                    Log.d("", "FileOutputStream: " + outputSource);

                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    isrecording = true;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[30 * 1024];
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytesRead];
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer2);

                        Log.d("","bytes size :"+buffer2.length);
                        Log.d("","bytesRead : "+bytesRead);

                    }


                } else if(isrecording){
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }
            } catch(Exception e){}
```

The problem here is that I'm receiving 30 as length of buffer2, and i cannot undersand why.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: What are the input and output format?

Comment: I always get the same number for `buffer2.length` and `bytesRead`, and it's never `30`. BTW, you shouldn't allocate `buffer2`. There is [`OutputStream.write(buffer, start, length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).
BTW for copying streams you can conveniently use [Apache IO utils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: Hi @android-droid ,me too searching for the same thing (how to record music from media player).If u have any sugeestion regarding this plz help mee..thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1):

```
    Button recstart, recstop,replay;
//onCreate
File f;
    File externalStorage;
    String path = "";
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    Timer time;
    String filename1 = "";
    boolean s = false;
externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String sdCardPath = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        path = sdCardPath + "/";

recstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    try {
                        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is "
                                + state + ".");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Date dt = new Date();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                String curTime = hours + "_" + minutes + "_" + seconds;

                filename1 = "phonecall_at" + curTime + ".mp4";
                if (recorder == null) {
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                }

                f = new File(path, filename1);
                try {
                    s = f.createNewFile();

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    // Toast.makeText(AudioRecording.this,"hiiiii...."+e1.getMessage(),2000).show();
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL +
                // MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
                // recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK
                // + MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK );
                if (s == true) {
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

                    recorder.setOutputFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    // record.setText("stop");
                    // record.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLUE);
                    // Toast.makeText(AudioRecording.this, String.valueOf(s),
                    // 3000).show();
                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                        Toast.makeText(AudioRecording.this, "Recording starts",
                                5000).show();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(".................................",
                                "" + e.toString());
                    }
                    recorder.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No space Left on device", 2000).show();
                }
                /*
                 * try { recorder.prepare(); Toast.makeText(Recordingvoice
                 * .this,"Recording starts",5000).show(); recorder.start();
                 * 
                 * 
                 * } catch (IllegalStateException e) { // TODO Auto-generated
                 * catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { //
                 * TODO Auto-generated catch block // e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }
        });
recstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (s == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(AudioRecording.this, "Recording stopped",
                            2000).show();
                    if (recorder == null) {
                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    }
                    if (recorder != null) {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();
                    }
                    recorder = null;
                    // time.cancel();
                    // uploadCode();
                }

            }
        });
replay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (f.exists()) {
                    Toast showMsg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    showMsg.show();
                    String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);
                    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp.setLooping(false);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(AudioRecording.this, myUri);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: As I can see you are using `MediaRecorder` class which is recording actually from microphone and all other sounds will be recorded too, for example if the user speaks during the recording and etc.

Comment: I don't need to record the speaking of user..I want to record only the output from media player.

Comment: So you simply need to store the content of the URL?

Comment: Yeah, but actually the most url are like `http://192.168.2.81:8000`, or `http://eilo.org/ambient.m3u` and similar to this..and I'm not realy sure how to save the streaming from these url addresses.

Comment: @Android-Droid I am also facing the same problem. Did you fin any solution?

Comment: I want to record only song played by player not user's voice which is being recorded by media recorder how can In block mic tha time. please help